Is there any linguistic or information-theory explanation for why typing in Chinese (using pinyin) is so efficient?
Typing in Chinese is amazingly efficient. The basic idea is that one types the romanization (pinyin) of the desired Chinese characters using a usual QWERTY keyboard.
The catch is that every Chinese input system comes with a built-in autocomplete/character recognition system that allows one to not have to type everything—often it suffices to type the first letter of each character.
This is especially true for common short phrases. For example:

"I like you" 我喜欢你 (wo xi huan ni) comes from simply typing 'wxhn'
"this is mine" 这是我的 (zhe shi wo de) from 'zswd'

One can even type "I think that the weather is very nice today": 我觉得今天天气特别好 (wo jue de jin tian tian qi te bie hao) from the acronym: 'wjdjttqtbh'. Though to be sure, this example is quite extreme, and usually for sentences of this length, it is rare that the first suggestion is what you actually want.
(As a further intro for non-Chinese speakers, this Youtube video from Johnny Harris is quite good, and also see this SCMP article for historical background.)
In theory, something like this can be implemented for any language. But I imagine, for example, that it wouldn't work very well for English, simply because there would be too many potential phrases/sentences for each sequence of letters.
So my question is whether there is any proper explanation for why such a system could work for some languages (e.g. Chinese) but maybe not others. That is, are some languages more "encodable" in some sense, and do such languages share certain information-theoretic properties? For example, maybe it's the case that written Chinese has particularly low "entropy" compared to other languages.

Well, for one thing, each character is exactly one syllable, so you’re predictably entering the first letter of every syllable, which is a lot more efficient than entering the first letter of every word would be in English. There may be as many as a few hundred common characters beginning with a specific letter, but words by first letter would number in the thousands easily. Going by syllable would also be a lot more convoluted in English – most English words are multisyllabic, and you’d have to resolve syllable boundaries in very specific, consistent ways in order for it to work.

Isn't it the other way? Chinese input method had to implement built-in autocomplete because it's too inefficient to use without it. Meanwhile, other languages like English didn't need it, because simply using one keystroke per character was already unambiguous and fast enough, so most people had no reason to search for a faster method.

@jick not really.  Pinyin is a reasonably efficient way of representing the sounds of Mandarin, so even if you have to type all the pinyin letters, it wouldn't be more inefficient than typing/writing in any other language. Chinese could get rid of characters and simply use pinyin as the writing system; the effect would be similar to Vietnamese, albeit worse due to more homophones.

But pinyin is not the end result of Chinese typing: you still have to convert individual syllables to actual Chinese characters. If Chinese speakers ditched Chinese characters and started using pinyin, then your statement would be true (not saying whether it's a good idea or not - it's a whole new issue), but that's not the case.

@jick There has to be an intelligent conversion from Pinyin-syllables to characters, yes. But the input systems do not need the second intelligent conversion from first-letter-of-Pinyin-syllable to full Pinyin-syllable to character. Typing woxihuanni is already as efficient as typing in English (I’d say it’s probably how most people would actually type it, though that’s pure anecdata). The fact that you can type out the full sentence with four keystrokes, wxhn, is what makes it different from English. You cannot type ily and get ‘I like you’ in English.

A somewhat comparable system for English would be T9 predictive text for mobile phones. Before the advent of touch screens on phones, the alphabet was represented on numeric keys, with three or four letters per key (2 = abc, 3 = def, 4 = ghi, etc.). The original way to type words would be to press the number multiple times (e.g., 22 33 4 for beg). T9 made it possible to hit each key just once, and the predictive dictionary would then guess which combination of letters was most likely (234 = beg).
